# Posicionamiento en css

Tags: html, css, responsive

La duda que tengo es la siguiente:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2rem;
    background-color: red
}

.hijo1 {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue
}

.hijo2 {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="hijo1"></div>
   <div class="hijo2"></div>
</div>
```

Aquí hay un div que contiene dos hijos, lo que quiero saber es como puedo hacer para que el div que está flotando a la izquierda tenga cierto ancho específico, en este caso `2rem` y que el otro div que está flotando a la derecha siempre este ocupan lo que queda del div padre sin importar el ancho de la pantalla.

Answer (score 4):

Con `display:flex;` lo puedes hacer también, te dejo un ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    * {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    }

 .container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
 }

 .hijo1 {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: green;
 }

 .hijo2 {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
 }
</style>

<body>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="hijo1"></div>
  <div class="hijo2"></div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Explicación:

Al div padre con la clase `.container` le apliqué `display:flex;` y a su hijo con la clase `.hijo2` le apliqué `flex-grow: 1;` en la que especifico cuanto espacio debe ocupar el elemento, si le pones 1, ocupará todo el espacio disponible que quede.

Con el `*` nos referimos a todos los elementos del body:

La propiedad `box-sizing` nos permite incluir el relleno y el borde en el ancho y alto total de un elemento.

Aplicando `box-sizing: border-box;` el relleno y el borde se incluyen en el ancho y la altura.

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación amigo de modo que sepamos que hiciste

Comment: Esta es la respuesta mas sencilla y organica, el uso de `display: grid` deberia limitarse a diseños en 2 dimensiones (filas y columnas), siendo este caso una sola fila, Flexbox es una mucho mejor opcion, y a regla `flex-grow` permite que el contenido escale naturalmente al espacio disponible

Answer (score 3):

Otra manera de lograrlo, claro esta quitando que los elementos estén flotando, es:

- Haciendo que el elemento sea `grid`
- Indicando en la creación de columnas que solo serán 2 y la primera es de 2rem y la restante es de 1 fr

  - De modo que de los 2 div que tiene internamente el primero ocupa una medida dada en rems y la segunda ocupará el espacio total disponible que queda

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <style>
      .container {
        background-color: red;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 2rem 1fr;
    
      }
      .hijo1 {
        background-color: tomato;
      }
      .hijo2 {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="hijo1">1</div>
       <div class="hijo2">2</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Un modo es con `display flex` y dando porcentajes o rem (unidades relativas) al ancho de los contenedores hijos. En el ejemplo en verde el segundo hijo para diferenciar del fondo rojo del contenedor.

```css
.container{
   width:100%;
   height: 2rem;
   background-color: red;
   display: flex;
}

.hijo1{
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: blue
}

.hijo2{
  width: 98rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color:green
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="hijo1"></div>
   <div class="hijo2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: no se si no me exprese bien o has entendido mal, lo que yo quiero es que el div azul tengo un ancho fijo solo de 2 rem y que el div verde sin importar el ancho de la pantalla siempre ocupe lo que sobra sin modificar los 2 rem del div azul

Comment: @Enzo cambiado ancho a rem, al ser unidades relativas es el mismo principio que con porcentajes

Comment: esto me ha estado volviendo loco siempre, muchísimas gracias carmen, que tengas un hermoso día

Answer (score 1):

lo que podrias haces es:

```
.hijo2{
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  height: 2rem;
  background-color:green
}
```

en el segundo hijo se calcula el ancho dela pantalla y se le resta los 2rem, lo que quede sera el ancho de este elemento.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma eficaz es:

- **display:flex;** al contenedor padre (con esto le estas diciendo que los elementos de dentro sean flexibles y se coloquen uno al lado del otro).
- **width: 100%;** darle un ancho del 100%  al hijo2 (este 100% significa el 100% de el espacio sobrante, ya que el hijo1 ya tiene sus 2rem de ancho y al haberle dado display flex al contenedor padre, hace que el ancho de los elementos de dentro se respeten entre ellos).
- **box-sizing: border-box;** si quisieras anyadirle margin o padding al contenedor padre, esto hace que los margenes no se desborden  fuera de la pagina (evitando así que se produzca el scroll horizontal al añadirlos).

```css
.container{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width:100%;
   padding: 2rem;
   background-color: red;
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
}

.hijo1{
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.hijo2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  float: right;
  background-color:#00ffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="hijo1"></div>
   <div class="hijo2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Así como lo tienes, sin flexbox ni css grid, puedes usar la función calc de css para que el navegador calcule la diferencia del div container menos el div hijo1.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2rem;
    background-color: red;
}

.hijo1 {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.hijo2 {
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="hijo1"></div>
   <div class="hijo2"></div>
</div>
```